# Check whether whether a subarray is in form of a mountain or not

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures

The question is

You have been given a array and then some number of query

For each query you have to check whether the sub-array forms a mountain or not. The query will be of the form [L,R] where L and R are the indices from the given array

More details can be obtained from the link
https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-whether-subarray-form-mountain-not/amp/

I figured out the brute force approach for each query.
But the website gives a better solution

I am having hard time to understand why that solution works.
I know that for the sub-array or any array to be a mountain

-it should be increasing for certain part and it should be decreasing for the rest

Detailed explanation as to why that solution given in the website works would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies if this is answer is a bit too elementary. I wasn't sure how familiar you might be with DP, so wanted to start from basics.

This is a Dynamic Programming solution, where the `left` and `right` arrays created in the `preprocess()` function serve the following purpose:

- For each index in the original array, `left` stores the left most index where the current value was greater than the previous (i.e. the length of the ascending part of the mountain, starting from index 0)
- Similarly, `right` stores the right most index where the current value was smaller than the last one (i.e. the length of the descending part of the mountain, starting from the last element)

With these two pieces of information, for any index `i` within the subarray you can tell if it lies in the descending or ascending part of the mountain.

If the subarray start index lies in the ascending part, and the end index lies in descending, you're good to go

```cpp
 return (right[L] >= left[R]);
```

Comment: I didnt got the last part...how to check if start index lies in ascending and end index lies in descending...

Comment: I added the corresponding line from the solution for the last part. Hope that helps!

Comment: Can you elaborate more on why right[L] >= left[R] ?

Comment: ok so by working little on examples i got the intuition. But every way i work around right[L]=left[R] for a subarray to be a mountain i am not getting why greater than equality is needed